# Could not create JVM while Installing Anypointstudio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have Issues while installing AnypointStudio Application on my Windows machine. I installed jdk-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5XI4.png)

**Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently released versions of Anypoint Studio are only compatible with Java/OpenJDK 8. Using Java 9-13 will cause issues like the one you are seeing. Use a version of Java/OpenJDK 8 instead. See the [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.4-with-4.2-runtime-update-site-2-release-notes#software-requirements) for details.